# Plugin issue (game centre and storekit)?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, prime31

I was trying to deploy a game to an iOS device,these error shows up. Now is this because the plugins need to be upgraded?

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "UnityGetGLViewController()", referenced from:
      +[GameCenterManager showViewControllerModallyInWrapper:] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      +[GameCenterManager dismissWrappedController:] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      +[GameCenterManager unityViewController] in libGameCenterPlugin.a(GameCenterManager.o)
      -[StoreKitManager displayStoreWithProductId:] in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
      ___45-[StoreKitManager displayStoreWithProductId:]_block_invoke in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
      -[StoreKitManager productViewControllerDidFinish:] in libStoreKit.a(StoreKitManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

We need solve this problem your unity version , xcode version. update please.
Now, just tell you **symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7** issue is generation in old plugin